# How to pass a string as a parameter with any quotation marks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I would like to ask quite a basic question.
I need to find how to send a string value in a function as a parameter without any quotation marks on it. such as.
my html file would look like :-

```
<p id='demo'>
</p>
```

and js code would be :-

```
function Random(data){
  document.getElementById("demo").data = "Paragraph changed!";
}

Random(textContent);
```

but it just doesn't work!
So can I use some other technique to get the job done, or is it basically impossible?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work?" What were you expecting to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: try this : `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Paragraph changed!";`

Comment: My question was general, I wanted to know how to access an attribute of an object using a string variable , and one of the guys answered me down below.. So cheers mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass a string "without quotes", in a JS program text that is not surrounded by quotes is not a [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), it is an [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_(computer_science)).

Your code doesn't work the way you think it should for a couple of reasons. First, you are not doing anything with the `data` parameter that is passed in. `.data` is a property of the DOM element you retrieved with `getElementById`. `data` is the literal name of the property you are accessing, it is not a reference to the value of the `data` parameter. In order to access a property with the name that you passed in as the `data` variable you will need to use [bracket notation instead of dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to access it:

```
function random(data) {
  document.getElementById("demo")[data] = "Paragraph changed!";
}

random("textContent");
```

You'll notice I changed the function name from `Random` to `random`. This is because it is a [convention in JS to only use capitalized names](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names) for [constructor functions](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/javascript-constructors-prototypes-and-the-new-keyword).

The other reason it isn't working is because of your attempt to use a "string" without quotes. When a JavaScript engine sees `random(textContent);` it interprets that as meaning call `random` passing the value of a variable named `textContent` as the first parameter. Since you have not defined a variable named `textContent` the value that is passed in is `undefined`. Quoting it turns it into a string literal, thus passing in the string you intended to.

Comment: I'm confounded as to why this (and the other answer) were down voted. If something was wrong with either, it would be nice to know what.

Comment: Thank you so much man! that is what I was looking forward to.. 
Thank you so much for the response! I am actually a beginner here in stack overflow.

Comment: I'm glad it helped and welcome to SO :-) If an answer is helpful, [you should](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) upvote it (normally [you need 15 reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) to upvote, which shouldn't be hard to get if you keep participating here on SO; I'm not sure if you can upvote answers on your own question without 15 rep or not). You should also mark the most helpful answer as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: man! I wanna upvote or mark it as most helpful, but I can't do either of them.. I ain't got 15 rep yet.. but once i get it, I'll come back to upvote.. I wonder who downvoted it tho.. your answer was absolutely perfect for me! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but if you want to access an attribute of an object using a string variable you will need to do it like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo")[data] = "Paragraph changed!"
```

Comment: Wow, I did not get that this is what he was asking...

Comment: Thanks man! i was looking forward about how to access the attribute.. but didn't know much of the terminology.. Cheers mate!